# how to:basic animation in as3 flashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, animated-gif, flashdevelop

I'm trying to add to my sprite an animation
what is the simple way to do it?
and where can i found tutorial for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/

There are you will find demo swfs which show how use it.

Comment: that not what i'm looking for..  i used to program games in xna and i had there a class that handled my animations.. i mean i had a bmp with all the frames of the animation and the class handled the speed of frame rate and things like that.. do u know something like that ?

Comment: You mean: you have images like this: http://migurazi.springnote.com/pages/4123577/attachments/2136535 and you need ability to control animation based on such image sprites?
-------------------------
If yes - look this:
http://blog.hexagonstar.com/animatedbitmapclass/

Comment: i think its over complicated .. i need something basic. in my game the player is some figure (like mario) i want him to walk not by tweening i want his legs to move. i dont really care how to do that . previously i used images similar to that u gave me. but i beleive (since almost every game have some anumations like that) that there should be a simple and well documented class for this kind of things but i couldnt find any

Comment: I break my comment to 2 parts (it have too many chars). Part1: 
The principle of this is simple: 
you have one bitmap which consists from several "frames" located one after the 
other (like this http://migurazi.springnote.com/pages/4123577/attachments/2136535) - I call it "sourceBitmapWithFrames". 
Also you have bitmap which show current "frame" - I call it "frameBitmap".
Also you have timer handler or Event.ENTER_FRAME handler at inside which you 
change "frame" to next.

Comment: Part 2: 
In order to change "frame" 
1) you clear frameBitmap (BitmapData::fillRect(frameBitmap.bitmapData.rect, 0x00000000)) 
2) use BitmapData::draw() or BitmapData::copyPixels() in order to copy pixels from 
next/desired "frame" from sourceBitmapWithFrames. 

You can write it yourself, you can look how it done inside com.hexagonstar.display.bitmaps.AnimatedBitmap, or you can just use it :)